# Google Chrome with strange behavior

Tags: google-chrome

I'm former Chromium-browser user, but after not upgrading the PPA for 2 months, I switched to Google Chrome browser yesterday. Everything is okay, except some strange behavior on some pages and crashing after loading "chrome://" configuration pages.
The best known website with strange behavior is youtube, there is a picture what I see:
[image: Youtube]
When I open user menu in top right corner, it crashes that way and even after closing the menu, some parts of menu stay display.

You may say it's Youtube problem, no, I have this problem at least on three other websites, here it is on Imgur:
[image]
The problem isn't for the whole side, sometimes it happens from the middle of the screen.

The interesting part is that it happens everytime in the same distance from the right border. When I check the DOM elements with the Developer tool, the overlay which shows element's position is rendered how it should be. What is more, if there is anchor after the crashed area, it works after clicking on it. Selecting text in crashed page is impossible.

I hope there is enough information to give me an advice, thanks in advance. :)

## EDIT:

Here is what the browser posted in "chrome://gpu-internals/":

```
Graphics Feature Status
Canvas: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
Compositing: Hardware accelerated
3D CSS: Hardware accelerated
CSS Animation: Software animated.
WebGL: Hardware accelerated
WebGL multisampling: Hardware accelerated
Problems Detected
Accelerated CSS animation has been disabled at the command line.
Accelerated 2d canvas is unstable in Linux at the moment.
```

Ubuntu 12.04 | 
Gnome-shell 3.4.1 | 
ATI Radeon 4550  | 
Screen resolution 1024*768 | 
Chrome version  20.0.1132.57 (Official Build 145807)

Comment: This seems to be a rendering problem, and so may be related with video driver which is encountering problem rendering graphics-rich screens, but then, if it's not happening with other browsers or windows, then it may be a bug of Google Chrome.

Comment: Yes, it happens only in Google chrome. There are even more pages affected, so I was forced to get back to Chromium-browser 18.* .

Comment: Could you type 'chrome://gpu-internals' into the address bar and cut/paste the parts that say 'Graphics Feature Status' and 'Problems Detected' ?

Comment: @MarkPaskal - I've edited my question.

Comment: On the latest version of Chrome / Chromium (Version 41.0.2272.76 - June 2015) the address to use is now `chrome://gpu`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might be that the newer version of Chrome simply does not like your GPU. I have had issues similar to yours and have solved them by turning off the compositing and 3d acceleration features.

Type `chrome://flags` into the address bar and set the following items:

**GPU compositing on all pages:** Disabled (Three options in a drop-down.)

**Disable accelerated 2D canvas:** Enable (Click the link that says 'Enable', the box will turn white.)

**Disable accelerated CSS animations:** Enable (Like above, the item will turn white.)

Then click the button that shows up at the bottom of the page `Relaunch now` to restart chrome and test if this worked.

Comment: Doesn't work for me with a ATI HD7970 and Linux Mint + Mate.

Comment: Try Jove' answer below and see if that works for you. The DE shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Nope, strange behaviour as always on Youtube, only on Youtube, I guess other sites were fixed through your solution.

Comment: The only option I had available of the three was `Disable accelerated 2D canvas` - enabling this seems to have cleared up the random white blocks that were appearing over pages in Chrome.

Comment: Incidentally, it is rather confusing but you need to `enable` the `disable` options to disable a function...

Comment: @Eborbob enabling the option means adding it's command line _flag_ to the string of text that gets fed to chrome at startup. So the option itself looks like "--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas" and 'enabling' it just adds this text to the command line.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and I learned this command from Google:

```
google-chrome  --blacklist-accelerated-compositing
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem myself with some versions of the Intel GM965/GL960 driver. I suggest that you try updating your video drivers. You didn't mention if are using fglrx or not.

Comment: They're using the official drivers, chrome blacklists the open source radeon driver and you can see from the chrome://gpu-internals that WebGL is hardware accelerated.

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu running in Virtualbox and at times Chrome's rendering issues would cause Ubuntu's rendering to crash forcing me to reboot the VM.  My solution is as the same as Jove's above but I've added an alias to my ~/.bashrc file that helps me start chrome quickly via a terminal:

```
alias chrome="google-chrome --blacklist-accelerated-compositing &"
```