# Graphical artifact in Chrome and Chromium

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

Since today I encounter weird graphical artifact when using Chromium ( makes it unusable).

It does not happen in Firefox or any other application.

Here is a screenshot :

[image: chromium artifact]

(Not visible in the screenshot but this also happens to the menu/tab bar. Not only in the page content.)

Out of curiosity I installed Chrome but the exact same thing happen.

I was wondering if it is a known problem with one recent update or if the problem come from my graphics card ?

---

**Additional information :**

Chromium version :

```
Version 45.0.2454.85 Ubuntu 15.04 (64-bit)
```

Chrome :

```
Version 45.0.2454.101 (64-bit)
```

Ubuntu :

```
 Ubuntu 15.04 "Vivid Vervet" (64-bit)
```

---

`lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` output :

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Richland [Radeon HD 8570D]
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 990e
    Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
```

Comment: Favorited o' liked, also a solution: try 32bit browsers, they function much better, however 32bit only function barely.

Comment: hve you tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167140/google-chrome-with-strange-behavior)

Comment: @Ravan yes, none of those solutions works...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turn off the hardware acceleration in the settings of google chrome.It should solve the problem.

For me, this solved the problem.

Comment: Yay, you saved my day as well!

Comment: For me, I had to turn on graphical acceleration.