# Firefox suffering graphical artifacts after sleep

Tags: graphics, firefox, suspend, visual-artifacts

Sometime, after having run for a long time and often after the computer is wake up from sleep, Firefox is suffering severe graphical artifacts / flickering on Ubuntu 18.04.

Here is an screen shot of such event, when I just resized the window to full screen by double clicking the main bar:

[image: Firefox is looking weird]
Still image, but it was really flickering like hell for a while, until I moved the window again.

As stated [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678211/graphical-artifact-in-chrome-and-chromium) for chromium, I also tried both with and without hardware acceleration in Firefox but nothing changes.

The page content is not displayed properly but it is actually there, in the background (I know that because when I click where links should be and when I move the window, even 1 pixel, the page actually went to that link. So moving the window is actually getting the content back on screen, and that's the only way I found until the next restart of the computer where things usually are fine for a while after reboot.

If anyone also experienced this issue and has found a way to solve it, I would be glad to hear about that.

#### System info

```
Laptop Lenovo T450s
Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS 5.4.0-62-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux
Mozilla Firefox 84.0.2
```